Is a question about code to generate passphrase appropriate here?
There are a couple of passprase generators out there, but all (I have found) use English words to build the passphrase. I wrote one using German words. Is it appropriate to discuss this code here with emphasis on security?

If it is about the code, No. If it is about the security aspects of passphrases, Maybe.

It is not about the code. It is more about the dictionary and the algorithm use to generate a passphrase.

Give it a shot and let's see.
